# Windows XP is locked, need to get back in

Tags: windows-xp, security, login

I have Windows XP with Administrator as user. I tried logging into the system, but after 3 failed attempts, am now locked out.

How do I get back in?

Comment: Why is this CWed?

Answer (score 6):

[The Offline NT Password Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/) lets you reset both the password, and the account's locked out status from a liveCD. It's included in UBCD and SysRecCD if you have those, or you can download it from the site.

Comment: +1 easy solution... but here I thought the default admin account isn't by default configured to lock-out interactive/console access at all?

Answer (score 4):

Well, my easiest suggestion would be to boot into safe mode (F8 during bootup before beep) and log onto the hidden administrator account and reset your own user password.

Otherwise, there's support.microsoft.com/kb/321305 or askvg.com/how-to-reset-recover-forgotten-windows-nt-2000-xp-2003-administrator-password/

Or you can even try OphCrack if you're feeling up to it (ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Use ERD Commander CD. Boot from it and you can reset the Administrator password.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both OphCrack and ERD Commander.  OphCrack is a fairly large download and may take around 30 minutes to display all local passwords on the machine.